# How to get a random friend of friend of someone in a facebook application using fql?

Tags: facebook-fql

How to get a random friend of friend of someone in a facebook application using fql?

here is some documentation but I cant find what im looking for :s

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user

somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would require permissions to access friends lists of friends of app. It's impossible for a user to grant privileges on behalf of friends, so you're out of luck.

Comment: only of friends that allows to see it's friends